# How to prove that $\sin \left(\frac 1 {x-1}\right)$ is discontinuous at $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Prove that $\sin \left(\frac 1 {x-1}\right)$ is discontinuous at $1$

I am fully aware that the limit does not exist at $x=1$ for the obvious reasons. I am asking for a simple proof of this that is fairly rigorous. In my answer I have used the Sandwich theorem (aka Pinch rule) to show $\sin$ is bounded by $1$ and $-1$. Since the limit of these are $1$ and $-1$ respectively as $x$ tends to $1$, the limits are different and therefore it doesn't exist. Is this correct?

Comment: This function isn't even defined for $x=1$, so it's not true that "it's continuous at $x=1$". What exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: I would reread what I have written if I were you

Comment: @DanielHolmes I would reread the definition of "function is continuous at" if I were you and check wether it requires "is defined at" as prerequisite. -- That being said, could it be that you simply ask whether $\lim_{x\to 1}\sin\frac1{x-1}$ exists?

Comment: Maybe I haven't worded the question very well. I know that the limit does not exist. I am asking how I can prove this. I know the definition - the left and right hand limit must be equal and this is not the case, however can I use the sandwich theorem to show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the standard question is to try define the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ and show that it is not continuous.
You want to show that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$, there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < \vert x \vert < \delta$ and
$$\vert \sin(1/x) \vert \geq \epsilon.$$
Here's a hint: pick $\epsilon = 1$ and remember that
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(2n + 1)\right) = \pm 1$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now
$$\frac{2}{\pi(2n + 1)}$$
can be made arbitrarily small by picking $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: This is pretty much what I am after I think :D does it not matter that it is shifted by -1?

Comment: No, because the translation will just shift the discontinuity.

Comment: In that case this is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to know that the sine stays between the boundaries, you need to use the fact that the boundaries are actually hit an infinite number of times as $x$ comes arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: Just wondering why this is the case?

Comment: Also what would you suppose I do instead. The other method I considered was using two subsequences that tend to different limits.

Comment: The sine function itself hits its maxima and minima at $\pm\frac\pi2$ plus integer multiples of $2\pi.$ To find the values of $x$ where the sine of $1/(x-1)$ is maximum or minimum, solve for $x$ and hope that you can build a convergent sequence from those solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Function, how it is defined at the moment, is discontinuous, because it is not defined at $x=1$. The right question: is it possible to define the fuction for $x=1$, that it becomes continuous.
Limit at point zero does not exist, neither from right nor from left.

Comment: It is defined at x=0. Sin(1/0-1)=Sin(-1)=-0.8414709848

Comment: You mean $x=1$, not $x=0$. The OP function is deliberately translated by $1$ for some reason

Comment: sorry, edited to $x=1$, content still the same

Answer (score 0):

A function needs to be *defined* throughout the range to be considered for the continuity test. The given function fails to be defined at x=1. Hence, the concept of continuity is out of question.

Comment: I am simply asking for a proof of why it is not continuous at x=1.

Comment: 1/0 = undefined. sin(undefined) is naturally undefined

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ approaches $1$ from both sides $\frac1{x-1}$ approaches infinity. What do you know about $\sin x$ when $x\to\infty$? It does not exist.

Comment: I don't think this is enough justification but you are correct.

Comment: what im actually doing is change of variables set y=x-1  y-->0 when x-->1.And see what happens it is rigorous enough if you prove that sinx at infinity does not exist which is easy. if you use  sequences such as $nπ$ and $((N+1)π)/2)$

Comment: I understand and never said this was difficult. More wondered if my justification was correct.

Comment: It is not sufficient to say that a function does not converge just because it has a max and min value.HAving a max and min value is not enough information. THe squeeze theorem is useful when the boundaries are converging to the same value if not the squeeze theorem does not say anything.

Comment: Ok I will explain more. Are you familiar with the sandwich theorem?

Comment: I edited my previous comment

Comment: Sandwich theorem is just a way to try and squeeze your function to a single value .Not finding a way to squeeze your function does not mean it cannot be squeezed Since there is not a way to know that you tried all possible ways to squeeze the function.It is a good way to prove continuity not to disprove.